# Delphi Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: delphi, fibonacci

i have an assignment for school where i have to write code so that i enter the first two terms and the every time i click a certain button the next term is printed on the memo output. But here is the twist, you cannot use if/else statements because they have not been taught to us.

```
    implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  iTerm1, iTerm2: integer;
  sOutput: String;

procedure TfrmFibonacciSequence.btnNextTermClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    iTerm3: integer;
  begin
    iTerm3 := iTerm1 + iTerm2;
    memOutput.Text := inttostr(iTerm3);
    sOutput :=
  end;

procedure TfrmFibonacciSequence.btnReadClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    iTerm1 := strtoint(edtFirst.Text);
    iTerm2 := strtoint(edtSecond.Text);
  end;

end.
```

that is what i have so far for the two buttons. the read button just reads the two input values(this is what the book wants) and then the next term button prints the next term in the sequence in the memo. i have no idea how i am supposed to keep it going forever and ever... especially without if/else statements.

please can someone help me out with this one.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.

When you click the `Next` button, you correctly compute the next value in the sequence: `iTerm1 + iTerm2`. You put this in `iTerm3`.

And the next time you click the `Next` button, you want to use `iTerm2` as the first term and this value, `iTerm3`, as your second. So make sure that will happen:

```
// For the next iteration:
iTerm1 := iTerm2;
iTerm2 := iTerm3;
```

Hence,

```
procedure TfrmFibonacciSequence.btnNextTermClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iTerm3: Integer;
begin
  iTerm3 := iTerm1 + iTerm2;
  memOutput.Text := IntToStr(iTerm3); // or iTerm3.ToString in modern Delphi
  // For the next iteration:
  iTerm1 := iTerm2;
  iTerm2 := iTerm3;
  // Maybe you also want to put iTerm1 and iTerm2 in the input edit boxes.
end;
```

Also, I'd recommend you to let your variables be members of your form class. Because otherwise very bad things will happen if you create two or more instances of this form class.

## Update

More explanation:

Currently, your `iTerm1` and `iTerm2` are global variables, so if you create two or more instances of `TfrmFibonacciSequence`, they will share these variables, and thus will not be able to function independently. It will be extremely confusing. So remove these global variables and instead add `iTerm1, iTerm2: Integer` to your form class.

```
type
  TfrmFibonacciSequence = class(TForm)
    edtFirst: TEdit;
    edtSecond: TEdit;
    btnRead: TButton;
    btnNext: TButton;
    memOutput: TMemo;
    procedure btnReadClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    iTerm1, iTerm2: Integer;
  public
  end;
```

This way, each instance of the class will have their own variables.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. If i wanted each term to stay on the memo output so that i can see all the values together, would that be possible? Also, I do not know what you mean by letting my variables be members of my form class??

Comment: @BaileyMcJarrow: Indeed. Just replace `memOutput.Text := (...)` with `memOutput.Lines.Add(...)`.

Comment: Currently, your `iTerm1` and `iTerm2` are global variables, so if you create two or more instances of `TfrmFibonacciSequence`, they will share these variables, and thus will not be able to function independently. It will be extremely confusing. So remove these global variables and instead add `iTerm1, iTerm2: Integer` to your form class.

Comment: So I should declare them below "procedure"? As a local variable?

Comment: No, that will not work. Then they will not survive between the invocations of the proc. They must be fields (members) of the class, so you get one variable of each *per class instance*. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ohh!!! Thank you so much! This really helped me, i really appreciate it.